# ESLint returns syntax error in new syntax in React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, eslint

ESLint catches errors in new syntax at functions. And underline '='

```
changefunction = () => {}
```

It's .eslintrc file

```
{
"extends": "react-app",
"rules": {
    "no-console": "warn",
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error"
},
"plugins": [ "babel", "react/recommended" ],
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: eslintrc.json

{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
},

"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "google"
],
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "react"
],
"rules": {
}

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: error  Parsing error: Unexpected token = and  Unexpected 'this'                                         no-invalid-this (in class component)

Answer (score 0):

How about change to `this.changefunction = () => {}`?